# Optimize Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I would like to know if there is a better way to do that :

```
//Menu text fadeOut
$(".fixed-menu ul li .menu-text, .submenu").fadeOut("slow", function() {

    //Extend menu and move the slider
    $menuExtend.stop().animate({"left": 30}, "slow");
    $sliderContent.stop().animate({"width": $(window).outerWidth() - 50}, "slow");
    $slider.stop().animate({"margin-left": 50}, "slow", function() {
        $(".fixed-menu ul li").css("width", "40px");
            $menuExtend.removeClass("minimize")
                    .addClass("extend")
                    .animate({"opacity": 1},"fast");

            $menuExtend.find("i").removeClass("foundicon-left-arrow")
                    .addClass("foundicon-right-arrow");
       });
});
```

When I use this code all the animation works but sometimes it's not perfectly fluid, is it only because JQuery animation need a lot of resources ?

I found a lot of tutorials about the Queue JQuery system but nothing with many and complex animation.

Thanks, Jordan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using `left` in conjunction with position: absolute instead of `margin-left` for your `$slider`. I imagine it might be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lian. Can you explain me why ?

Comment: Animating left is faster than animating margin-left. Source: http://jsperf.com/left-vs-margin-left-animation

Comment: That being said, CSS3 is much faster than using jQuery. This article explains why: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to SO. Kindly accept the answer if it answered your question.